# How to check if it is a good captcha?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, captcha

I'm implementing a captcha system using this code: http://www.thomasmoore.it/webdesign/asp/captcha.asp

As you can see in that page there is an example of image with alphanumeric characters.

Below an example:

[image]

I would like to understand if that image is strong enough or not. 
Do you know if there are scripts that can break it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how answer your question but i suggest using controls that have been used and tested before..like [recaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha)

Comment: thank you for your reply... I would like to understand if imgs like that could be "read" or not.... btw, I will also look at recaptcha.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use it, not because it's not safe, but because it's not accessible. What if your users use screenreaders? Stay with an accessible solution such as recaptcha and make your users happy ;)

As for the security, mine may be a controversial opinion, but I think it doesn't matter so much. Why? because if an attacker is serious about breaking your site, they can use the [Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com) or one of the bazillion online services that offers to solve *any captcha* by hand for a really low price. Of course a good captcha is one more barrier for them to break, but don't trust them too much.